# Dio in flutter doesn't finalize the function then not update FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dio

I dont know what I did then Dio stoppped to finalize the function that posts the value to the server. The function execute the query but the FutureBuilder never change the state.... here's the code, does anyone have any tip on it?

```
Widget dropDownLanguage() {
 return FutureBuilder(
  future: _futureRetorno ,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
   Map valoresUsuario = _userLanguages.asMap();
   print(_userLanguages);
   } else {
   return Center(
     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
   );
    }
  }
 );
}

Future <List> loadUserSettings() async{
 FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
   "action" : "user_settings",
   "usuario_id": _usuario_id,
 });
 _userLanguages = await repository.consultaWS(formData);
 print("finalizado");
 return _userLanguages;
}


 @override
  void initState()  {
   _futureRetorno = loadUserSettings();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the server was responding with a header `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');` and it should be `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');`

It was not Dio fault, PHP instead...